# Why doesn't Query pull up Data when using Where Function to reference a number

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am relatively new to using the Query function but I would like to understand what I'm doing wrong in the following scenario.

I would like to pull from a table with a Year field in column F and Month field in column G. The query pulls correctly when filtering column E and J but returns nothing once I add either column F or G. This is weird because the source table contains a lot of data for the conditions (verified by filtering the source table). Any idea what could be going wrong?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Add some sample of columns E, F,  G , J, M and O and the corresponding expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the single quotes around concatenations for numbers; otherwise the QUERY is looking for strings.

Ex:

```
"... where ... F ="&A3&" and ..."
```

not

```
"... where ... F ='"&A3&'" and ..."
```

Same with `"and G ="`

Comment: Thank you however when I took out the single quotes I ended up with a #value...

Comment: actually I just got it to work. amazing! I don't understand the reasoning behind why you need single quotes are for text matches and no single quotes for numbers but it works!

Comment: There are three major data types: boolean, string and number. And code treats them differently. Quotes denote string values; think of a string as a way to tell a computer "treat this as exactly what I entered and don't assign it a value." So the string "44217" (in quotes) might be the zip code for Creston, Ohio (which we don't want to add, subtract or interpret; whereas the number 44217 (without quotes) is either the number forty-four-thousand-two-hundred-seventeen (with which math CAN be done) or a raw date (44217 days since December 31, 1899—which can also be manipulated with math).

Comment: Continuing from above, the string "17" (in quotes) might be part of a street address (e.g., "17 Smith Lane"), where the number 17 (without quotes) might be a number of items in stock or an age—which we might want to do math with later. And in case you were interested, boolean values are TRUE and FALSE, which do NOT go in quotes, because they DO have interpreted meaning in code as well as assigned valued (FALSE being equal to 0 and TRUE being equal to 1).

Comment: If my post answer addressed your original question then, which it sounds like it did, please take a moment to mark it as "Best Answer." This will let others know that this issue has been resolved, as well as helping future site visitors more easily find answers.

Comment: Thanks so much. This was really helpful and I appreciate you taking the time. I've marked as solved.

Comment: One more clarification - When you are referrng to quotes do mean single quote or double quote. It appears that the function of double quote is to allow for a cell reference whereas the single quote is meant to indicate the string. The working formulas was the following, where F and G were the year and month value. 

=query(GL_Load,"select F, G, M, O where E = '"&A1&"' and J = '"&A2&"' and F = "&A3&" and G = "&A4&"",1)

Comment: continuing from above... Part of my confusion is that the formula would treat letters and numbers differently by default because in theory, shouldn't Year (2020 in this case) work as a string the same as if it were text? Like my particular use case, I just need to pull the rows with 2020 as a value - the same as if it were text.

Comment: The only reason you'd have single quotes in your formula is because the "Select..." clause of the QUERY is already in double quotes. It's the same rules as English grammar in that sense, i.e., quotes within quotes use single quotation marks. And, no, "2020" is not the same as 2020. They do not match in memory, because they are seen as two different data types that take up different amounts of virtual space (bytes). You have to match data type as well as characters, which means you need to know what your source data type is from the outset.

Comment: If your 2020 is a string, then you'd need quotes to search for it. If it's a number, you must NOT have quotes to search for it. You can tell your data type by choosing some empty cell and typing, for instance, =ISNUMBER(A3). If this returns TRUE, it's a number. If this returns FALSE, it's a string. They may LOOK the same, however, in the cell (though without formatting, numbers align right and strings align left in cells). In your case, you've aligned everything right, so you'd have to use formulas to check.

Comment: Really helpful and makes total sense. Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome.